# MFMailComposeViewController custom navigation buttons?

Tags: ios, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

What is the best way to use custom background images for the "cancel" and "send" buttons (`barbuttonitems`) in `MFMailComposeViewController`?

**A/N:** I know about the note on Apple's website about not changing interfact, but I need to do this for consistency throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can always send the email in the background and control how the form and email buttons look. Take a look at this post and the answer on how to do that.

[Locking the Fields in MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-question-locking-the-fields/6287412#6287412)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the look of the navigationbar, cancel and send button, through app delegate.

Try this code:

```
UIImage*resizedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar1"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 12, 12, 10)];
id navbar =[UINavigationBar appearance];
id barbutton =[UIBarButtonItem appearance];

//this customises the navigation bar 
[navbar setBackgroundImage:resizedImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
UIImage *backButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton"]  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10 , 18, 10 , 18)];

// this customises the back bar button item in the navigation bar
[barbutton setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


// this for other bar button items 
[barbutton setBackgroundImage:backButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: This works with one exception: It seems MFMailComposeViewController ignores the resizingMode parameter:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-main.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`