# How to send textfields content via email in the background?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, email, uitextfield

I'm trying to make a simple view based application.

I want to receive information with the content of text fields when user filled text fields and hits the submit button.

The way I do this doesn't matter so much. It can be done by sending information to a web server or sending information to my e-mail in background. Actually it seems easier to do it via e-mail.

I just want to know what the user wrote on text fields when he hit the submit button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083261/how-to-send-an-email-to-a-receipent-in-background-in-ios5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087199/xcode-4-ios-send-an-email-using-smtp-from-inside-my-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library

Comment: I can't say I know the answer to your question, but there is no need to apologize for your English. You seem to have better sentence structure and grammar than a lot of native speakers.

Comment: You could send them to a remote server, and let that server deal with sending the emails

Comment: @Yetik make directly a simple form on a remote server. Call the .php file from UIWebView, that is the most simple way to go for a beginner.