# how to send email using UIbarbuttonitem without using MFMailComposerViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, uibarbuttonitem, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send email using rightBarButtonItem without using MFMailComposerViewController.
Is It possible to send email using barButtonItem?

Any Idea how to do this?

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a fantastic code sample on the accepted answer here to send a background email:

[Locking the Fields in MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-question-locking-the-fields)

All you need to do is setup your rightBarButtonItem's target to fire a method containing this email code, and then populate the message contents etc using the information you want to send.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set an action method for the right bar button item and thus, you can make a direct call to open the email client and compose a mail.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://testmailer@somemail.com"]];
```

This is just a quick fix or may be something you were looking for!