# How to send email using UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to send email using UIbarbuttonitem without using MFMailComposerViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223121/how-to-send-email-using-uibarbuttonitem-without-using-mfmailcomposerviewcontroll)

As shown in the image this app used to send mail on send button's click.

I found that it is not showing MFMailComposerViewController.

[image]

How can it be possible? How do I get this functionality?

Comment: can you edit your question to show the code / action method that gets fired when you click on the "Send" bar button?

Comment: This image is of demo app and I want to implement such kind of functionality in my app. so I don't have any code and knowledge.

Comment: Please just edit your original question if you want to provide more context or detail.

Comment: Do I need to present MFMailComposerViewController every time? I don't want to present it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)MailButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        //atableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
        //[socailNetworkView removeFromSuperview];
    //  self.navigationItem.title = @"Contents";
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailViewController setSubject:@""];
        [mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"", nil];


        NSArray *mailArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:string,nil];
        [mailViewController setToRecipients:mailArr];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
        [mailViewController release];

    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"Device is unable to send email in its current state");

    }
}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error;

{

    NSLog(@"Mail");
    NSString  *str=@"";
    switch (result) {  
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:  
            NSLog(@"Mail send canceled.");  
            str=@"\nMail sending cancelled";
            //msgLabel.text=str;
            //          [msgLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:18]];
            //          msgLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(54.0/255.0) green:(2.0/255) blue:(1.0/255) alpha:1.0];

            /* 
             Execute your code for canceled event here ... 
             */  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:  
            NSLog(@"Mail saved."); 
            str=@"Mail saved";
            /* 
             Execute your code for email saved event here ... 
             */  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:  
            NSLog(@"Mail sent.");  
            str=@"Mail sent";
            /* 
             Execute your code for email sent event here ... 
             */  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:  
            str=@"Mail not sent";
            NSLog(@"Mail send error: %@.", [error localizedDescription]);  
            /* 
             Execute your code for email send failed event here ... 
             */  
            break;  
        default:  
            break;  
    }
    //alertLabel.text=str;
    //  [viewAlert setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //  [self.view addSubview:viewAlert];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, Saranya (and I am +1'ing it). You should clean up the formatting, though.

Comment: Thank you and sure i'l update...i just sent the answer suddenly without formatting ;)

Comment: does it open default MFMailComposerView?

Comment: Yes...add the mail button function to your button click. It will open the default MFMailComposerView.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to read a tutorial carefully.

I found this via Google:

[New In iPhone 3.0 Tutorial Series, Part 2: In App Email, MessageUI](http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/)

Yes, it says "iPhone 3.0" but the same concepts and code should work perfectly fine in iOS 5.