# UIMessage "sending direct mail"

Tags: iphone

I am developing an exam app. After the completion of the exam, if the person presses the done button, the results will be sent directly to the person's email.

I know how to use the `MessageUI` framework, but i don't want to get any compose view - instead it should go directly to the concern email.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer in the following thread for a method on how to send a background email: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-question-locking-the-fields

Answer (score 1):

For example syntax :

```
    NSString *msgToSend = @"This is an Example Message to be send";
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.home.com?method=aMethodName&msg=%@",msgToSend]; //here msg is a parameter of your url string
    NSLog(@"%@",urlStr);
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

Hope it gives you an idea...

Comment: it helps me a lot and make my work easy Thank you very much:-)

Comment: i want to give mailed instead of website were asNSString //*urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kumar@gmail.com?method=aMethodName&msg=%@",msgToSend];// is it a correct way to do..? i am sending the mail but the mail is not going??????

Comment: No no no... as you mentioned you have web service that sends mail so you have to write web service's URL instead of ""kumar@gmail.com". By this you call the web service by passing the string (your msg)as parameter and your back system receives the msg and take appropriate action to send the mail to the desired location.

Comment: i have SMTP for Outgoing How can i configure it to this NSURL? Kindly let me know i am completely new to this iPhone Please.

Comment: for that you should contact with your .NET or php team :D

Comment: I mean[@"smtp.zaimail.yahoo.comUSERNAME:XYZPASS:XYZ"?method=aMethodName&msg=%@",msgToSend] is it a correct way to put username and password and id?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible but for this you need a webservice which will send the mail.

Comment: ya i have web service can you let me know how?

Comment: Then just use it as NSURL and pass the emailid and msg to the url. Actually this will be dependent on how your webservice is designed

Comment: how can i send the msg in NSURL can you give me the Syntax please?

Comment: @Maulik: i am new to iPhone can please give me ex: Syntax

Comment: @Maulik: i want to give mailed instead of website were asNSString //*urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"kumar@gmail.com?method=aMethodName&msg=%@",msgToSend];// is it a correct way to do..? i am sending the mail but the mail is not going??????