# automatic background email from iphone application to users

Tags: iphone

I am so confused. My simple requirement is: i have an application which contains confirmation form i.e. nib file. It contains some textFields like name, age, email etc. I simply want when somebody click on submit button application send background and automatic email to email defined in textField. that email contain all information like name, age etc. User need not to fil anything and it should work in background. There are so many application do the same thing. I am creating booking application.

So how can i impliment this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this:

1. Send an HTTPS POST request to your server application.
2. From your server application, send an email via SMTP (or APIs built on top of SMTP).

[Google AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) provides a simple and cheap way to create such a web service, running on top of Google's cloud-computing infrastructure. The [sending mail from AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html) help document includes detailed examples of how to send mail from your server application (assuming you use the Python version of Google AppEngine).

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not provide a way to do this - and for good reason. Sending emails from the phone automatically introduces a lot of security risks.

I am willing to bet that the apps that do this use an intermediary server to which they post the data. When the data is posted then the server handles the sending of the emails.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no official feature for this but you could download a third-party library. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827014/iphone-sdk-send-email-in-background-in-iphone-app) for a couple of suggestions.