# Send Image Using web service or Email using Smtp?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, smtp

In my application i want to send images to user without their interaction.which option is better
Through Web service or
Through Smtp email

if user press home button while image sending is in progress.apple provides 10 minutes to complete your small tasks. which of them will perform better ?

is there any chance of app rejection if i use webservice or Smtp Email ?

thanks
jawad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any chance of app rejection if i use webservice or Smtp Email ?

> > NO application will not rejected.BUt User confirmation needed.

Comment: Are you sure ? any confirmation link or apple guideline link ?

Comment: check this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe

Answer (score 2):

It's better to send it by web service. As apple's privacy policy says you can't send Email or SMS without user's Interaction. If you send the image using Email there are chances of your app getting rejected.

Regarding the performance web service will work fine.

Comment: Sending email in the background without the MailComposer won't be a problem. Im using that code in about 15 of my Live apps. Apple might want to see the user click "Send Score" though, and not just have you send it and THEN notify them that it was sent. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: written here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827014/iphone-sdk-send-email-in-background-in-iphone-app

Comment: 17. Privacy

17.1
Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used

It's from https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: what do you say about the answer given below ?